# php websoket One or more reserved bits

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am working on php web socket I had successfully created web socket and other devices are successfully connected with it. But after some time it will not allow us to connect.I am getting this error:

```
êInvalid reserved bit WebSocket connection to 'ws://xyz.com:9000/' failed: One or more 

reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1
```

Most of the times it is working fine, but after a time period if no device connected with socket it is not allowing any device or web to connect.

I had search on Google and send a ping to device from server but it is not helping me...